# d3 example for network visualization having collapsible zoom feature

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I have done an intensive search on this topic, and its really hard to find any example on this.

Little background:

I am beginner at d3 trying to build a network visualization that can **collapse its nodes when zoomed out**. Perfect example of what I am talking about is here:
http://www.twittercensus.se/graph2013/ or even googlemaps (not sure how they do it, but i would like to do the same using d3.js)

Idea is not to display all the nodes (10K+), but group them and show only the groups. When I zoom-in, the group should expand (assuming all nodes are spaced out using collision detection)

Again, just to be clear, when I zoom in, I don't want the nodes to look larger in size, but instead I want a collapsing feature where a consolidated node break into smaller nodes.

Some useful links:

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675 - example of d3 normal zoom-in (no collapsible feature)
- [D3.js Zooming and panning a collapsible tree diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405638/d3-js-zooming-and-panning-a-collapsible-tree-diagram) - again, this just shows how to hide nodes when collapsed (no zoom-collapsible feature interaction)
- [Collapsible/hierarchical AND force-directed graph in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927671/collapsible-hierarchical-and-force-directed-graph-in-d3-js) - useful examples showing collapsing network, but not in a zoom-in manner. (no zoom feature)

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the code in your second and third links, and you will have your answer.